# BeautifulSoup find the next specific tag following a found tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Given the following (simplified from a larger document)

```
<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Age</td>
  <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Height</td>
  <td>5.6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Weight</td>
  <td>103.4</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried to return the `16` from the appropriate row using `bs4` and `lxml`. The issue seems to be that there is a `Navigable String` between the two `td` tags, so that

```
page.find_all("tr", {"class":"row-class"})
```

yields a result set with

```
result[0] = {Tag} <tr class="row-class"> <td>Age</td> <td>16</td> </tr>
result[1] = {Tag} <tr class="row-class"> <td>Height</td> <td>5.6</td> </tr>
result[2] = {Tag} <tr class="row-class"> <td>Weight</td> <td>103.4</td> </tr>
```

which is great, but I can't get the string in the second `td`. The contents of each of these rows is similar to

```
[' ', <td>Age</td>, ' ', <td>16</td>, ' ']
```

with the `td` being a `tag` and the `' '` being a `Navigable String`. This difference is preventing me from using the `next_element` or `next_sibling` convenience methods to access the correct text with something like:

If I use:

```
find("td", text=re.compile(r'Age')).get_text()
```

I get `Age`. But if I try to access the next element via

```
find("td", text=re.compile(r'Age')).next_element()
```

I get

> 'NavigableString' object is not callable

Because of the wrapping `NavigableStrings` in the `result`, moving backwards with `previous_element` has the same problem.

How do I move from the found `Tag` to the next `Tag`, skipping the `next_element` in between? Is there a way to remove these `' '` from the `result`?

I should point out that I've already tried to be pragmatic with something like:

```
    for r in (sp.find_all("tr", {"class":"row-class"})):
        age = r.find("td", text=re.compile(r"\d\d")).get_text()
```

it works ... until I parse a document that has another order with a matching `\d\d` before `Age`.

I know, also, that I can

```
find("td", text=re.compile(r'Age')).next_sibling.next_sibling
```

but that is hard-baking the structure in.

So I need to be specific in the search and find the `td` that has the target string, then find the value in the next `td`. I know I could build some logic that tests each row, but it seems like I'm missing something obvious and more elegant...

Answer (score 4):

if you get list of elements then you can use `[index]` to get element from list.

```
data = """<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Age</td>
  <td>16</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Height</td>
  <td>5.6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-class">
  <td>Weight</td>
  <td>103.4</td>
</tr>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

trs = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"row-class"})

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td") # you get list

    print('text:', tds[0].get_text()) # get element [0] from list
    print('value:', tds[1].get_text()) # get element [1] from list
```

result

```
text: Age
value: 16
text: Height
value: 5.6
text: Weight
value: 103.4
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I could do this (having done it many times before). If you look at the `for` loop in my post, you'll see basically what you are calling for. That's what I meant when I wrote `I know I could build some logic that tests each row` but here I'm looking at finding a supported approach or such within the convenience methods in bs4 that will let me skip to the next `tag` sibling or something else elegant like that!